# Bigram frequency of query logs events with Apache Spark

Tags: scala, session, pattern-matching, apache-spark, sequence

I would like to study user actions within sessions extracted from search engine query logs. I define first two kinds of actions : Queries and Clics.

```
sealed trait Action{}
case class Query(val input:String) extends Action
case class Click(val link:String)  extends Action
```

Suppose that first action in the query log is given by the following timestamp in milliseconds :

```
val t0 = 1417444964686L // 2014-12-01 15:42:44
```

Let's define a corpus of temporally ordered actions associated to sessions ids.

```
val query_log:Array[(String, (Action, Long))] = Array (
("session1",(Query("query1"),t0)), 
("session1",(Click("link1") ,t0+1000)), 
("session1",(Click("link2") ,t0+2000)), 
("session1",(Query("query2"),t0+3000)), 
("session1",(Click("link3") ,t0+4000)), 
("session2",(Query("query3"),t0+5000)), 
("session2",(Click("link4") ,t0+6000)), 
("session2",(Query("query4"),t0+7000)), 
("session2",(Query("query5"),t0+8000)),
("session2",(Click("link5") ,t0+9000)),
("session2",(Click("link6") ,t0+10000)),
("session3",(Query("query6"),t0+11000))
)
```

And we create a RDD for this quey_log :

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
var logs:RDD[(String, (Action, Long))] = sc.makeRDD(query_log)
```

The logs are then grouped by session ids

```
val sessions_groups:RDD[(String, Iterable[(Action, Long)])] = logs.groupByKey().cache()
```

Now, we want to study Action cooccurrences within a session, for example, the numbers of rewritings in a sesssion. We then define the class Cooccurrences which will be initialized from session actions.

```
case class Cooccurrences(
  var numQueriesWithClicks:Int = 0,
  var numQueries:Int = 0,
  var numRewritings:Int = 0,
  var numQueriesBeforeClicks:Int = 0
 ) {
 // The cooccurrence object is initialized from a list of timestamped action in order to catch a session group
  def initFromActions(actions:Iterable[(Action, Long)]) = {
    // 30 seconds is the maximal time (in milliseconds) between two  queries (q1, q2) to consider q2 is a rewririting of q1
    var thirtySeconds = 30000 
    var hasClicked = false 
    var hasRewritten = false
    // int the observed action sequence, we extract consecutives (sliding(2)) actions sorted by timestamps
    // for each bigram in the sequence we want to count and modify the cooccurrence object
    actions.toSeq.sortBy(_._2).sliding(2).foreach{ 
      // case Seq(l0) => // session with only one Action 
      case Seq((e1:Click, t0)) => { // click without any query
        numQueries = 0        
      }
      case Seq((e1:Query, t0)) => { // query without any click
        numQueries = 1        
        numQueriesBeforeClicks = 1
      }
      // case Seq(l0, l1) => // session with at least two Actions
      case Seq((e1:Click, t0), (e2:Query, t1)) => { // a click followed by a query
        if(! hasClicked)
          numQueriesBeforeClicks = numQueries
        hasClicked = true
        }
      case Seq((e1:Click, t0), (e2:Click, t1)) => { //two consecutives clics 
        if(! hasClicked)
          numQueriesBeforeClicks = numQueries
        hasClicked = true
      }
      case Seq((e1:Query, t0), (e2:Click, t1)) => { // a query followed by a click
        numQueries += 1
        if(! hasClicked)
          numQueriesBeforeClicks = numQueries
        hasClicked = true
        numQueriesWithClicks +=1
      }
      case Seq((e1:Query, t0), (e2:Query, t1)) => { // two consecutives queries
        val dt = t1 - t0
        numQueries += 1
        if(dt < thirtySeconds && e1.input != e2.input){
          hasRewritten = true
          numRewritings += 1
       }
      }
    }
  }
```

}

Now, let's try to compute a RDD of Cooccurrences for each session :

```
val session_cooc_stats:RDD[Cooccurrences] = sessions_groups.map{ 
  case (sessionId, actions) => {
   var coocs  = Cooccurrences()
   coocs.initFromActions(actions)
   coocs
  }
 }
```

Unfortunately, it raises the following MatchError

```
scala> session_cooc_stats.take(2)

15/02/06 22:50:08 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) scala.MatchError: List((Query(query3),1417444969686), (Click(link4),1417444970686)) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon) at $line25.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Cooccurrences$$anonfun$initFromActions$2.apply(<console>:29)
  at $line25.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Cooccurrences$$anonfun$initFromActions$2.apply(<console>:29)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
  at $line25.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Cooccurrences.initFromActions(<console>:29)
  at $line28.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:31)
  at $line28.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:28)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
  at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$26.apply(RDD.scala:1081)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$26.apply(RDD.scala:1081)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1314)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1314)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/02/06 22:50:08 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, localhost): scala.MatchError: List((Query(query3),1417444969686), (Click(link4),1417444970686)) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
  at $line25.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Cooccurrences$$anonfun$initFromActions$2.apply(<console>:29)
  at $line25.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Cooccurrences$$anonfun$initFromActions$2.apply(<console>:29)
 ...
```

If I build my own action list equivalent to the first group in session_cooc_stats RDD

```
val actions:Iterable[(Action, Long)] = Array(
(Query("query1"),t0),
(Click("link1") ,t0+1000),
(Click("link2") ,t0+2000),
(Query("query2"),t0+3000),
(Click("link3") ,t0+4000)
)
```

I get the expected result

```
var c = Cooccurrences()
c.initFromActions(actions)
// c == Cooccurrences(2,2,0,1)
```

Something seems wrong when I build a Cooccurrence object from a RDD.
It seems linked to the CompactBuffer built with groupByKey().
What is missing ?

I am new to Spark and Scala. 
Thanks by advance for your help.

Thomas

Comment: I just plugged it in and it works for me...

Comment: Can you really execute the Spark instruction  `session_cooc_stats.take(2)` without any changes ? 

I m still getting a scala.MatchError on List((Query(query3),1417444969686), (Click(link4),1417444970686))

Answer (score 0):

As you advised, I rewrote the code with IntelliJ and created a companion object for the main function.
Surprisingly, the code compiles (with sbt) and runs flawlessly.

However, I don't really understand why compiled code runs whereas it doesn't work with spark-shell.

Thanks you for your answer !

Answer (score -2):

I set your code upon IntelliJ.

Create one class for Action, Query, Click, and Coocurence.

And your code on a main.

```
val sessions_groups:RDD[(String, Iterable[(Action, Long)])] = logs.groupByKey().cache()

  val session_cooc_stats:RDD[Cooccurrences] = sessions_groups.map{
    case (sessionId, actions) => {
      val coocs  = Cooccurrences()
      coocs.initFromActions(actions)
      coocs
    }
  }
  session_cooc_stats.take(2).foreach(println(_))
```

Just modified var coocs > val coocs

I guess that the point.

Cooccurrences(0,1,0,1)

Cooccurrences(2,3,1,1)